# Is there an idiom/phrase for the situation where people hang out in a foyer saying goodbye, but not leaving?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, idiom-requests

The situation is after some event, like a dinner or a party, and the last people to leave are saying their goodbyes.  Then, just as they're at the door, they start chatting with the host, and before anyone realizes it, they've been standing in the foyer for about 1-2 hours and still haven't left.

I've been in this situation often, and for some reason I thought it had a name or phrase, like "suck in the foyer saying goodbye" or something.

I tried googling it, and I got results like "long goodbye", when someone says goodbye to someone they know they won't see for a long time, which is not at all what I'm looking for.

Comment: I call it ***doorway talk***. Happens all the time.

Comment: @NVZ It does appear to be a duplicate.  I looked at all the suggested questions, and googled a bit, but couldn't find that question.

Comment: And the truth is, there may not be a good answer to this question yet.

Comment: _ *Then, just as they're at the door, they start chatting with the host, and before anyone realizes it, they've been standing in the foyer for about 1-2 hours and still haven't left* _ It is called a "fascinating conversation!"

Comment: chatterbox-ing, chewing the fat, discoursing, Foot-in-the-Door chat/gibber - if you will